# Upsert & increment in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

Is it possible to do an "upsert" with an increment?
So if the query is an insert the counter will **initialize** with **1** and if it an update it will **increment** the counter by **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.insert({id: 1, counter: 1}, {conflict: function(id, oldVal, newVal) {
  return newVal.merge({counter: oldVal('counter').add(1)})
}})
```

Introduced in v2.3.0 IIUC:
https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/releases/tag/v2.3.0

Comment: Apologies, I'm not a rethinkdb guru, but wouldn't this require `counter` to be unique? I thought RethinkDB only supported uniqueness on the primary key (which in this example I would assume is `id`)